# if else statements formulation

Tags: c#, c++

Maybe there was same question, but I don't know how to formulate it. 
Is it any difference between:

```
int x = 0;
if( someCondition )
{
    x = 1;
}
```

And

```
int x;
if( someCondition )
{
    x = 1;
}
else
{
    x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Both will do the same thing.

Comment: No there's technically no difference, besides always to prefer initializing variables (not necessary in c# IIRC).

Comment: Result is same, but any difference in performance or anything else?

Comment: No differences except if you get an exception.  The 2nd method would may not set x to 0 when an exception occurs.

Comment: @Mažas _"but any difference in performance or anything else?"_ You have to pick a language first that this could be reasonably answered.

Comment: @Mažas i would think in most compilers this would give you basically the same performance. In both cases you allocate space for an integer and assign a value depending on a condition, which is evaluated in every case.

Comment: Remember that C++ have things like copy-constructors and operator overloading. In ***this specific case*** with an `int` variable it really doesn't matter (semantically or for performance), but there might be a very big difference if you use a class which have a custom copy-constructor or assignment operator defined.

Comment: Pick a language...?

Answer (score 4):

Little questions like this are very easy to test on online compilers such as godbolt:

```
int test1(bool someCondition)
{
  int x = 0;
  if( someCondition )
  {
    x = 1;
  }
  return x;
}

int test2(bool someCondition)
{
  int x;
  if( someCondition )
  {
    x = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    x = 0;
  }
  return x;
}

int test3(bool someCondition)
{
  return someCondition ? 1 : 0;
}

int test4(bool someCondition)
{
  return int(someCondition);
}
```

resulting assembler:

```
test1(bool):
        movzx   eax, dil
        ret
test2(bool):
        movzx   eax, dil
        ret

test3(bool):
        movzx   eax, dil
        ret
test4(bool):
        movzx   eax, dil
        ret
```

so in reality, no. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: @Afflicted there is an implicit else in setting the variable to zero before the test.

Comment: link to godbolt for those interested: https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is clever enough to understand that it is exactly the same, and will generate the same code.

The difference is in readability and maintainability; if you have either versions as a part of a larger program, it should reflect the logical concepts of what is done.